# error loading after build

Tags: c++, opencv, build

I'm generally new to openCV and c++. I'm developing in Ceemple IDE and managed after some problems to get no errors during the compilation. the struggle though is not over as i get the following messages in the terminal

```
Compilation OK. Creating machine code... Code generating 'detectAndDisplay()'
Linking... [94;106mLinking OK.[39;49m [94;106mFinished compiling (0.21+0.22=0.42 sec) and linking (0.59 sec).[39;49m
11:21:19 Build Finished (took 1s.822ms) --
(!)Error loading
```

have you got any clue of what this mught be? thank you!

Comment: hint: the error is *literary* in the code !

Answer (score 1):

Which code are you trying to run?
Maybe the code tries to open some image file which isn't there?